# Want to clean data inside location table using snowflake which has country,state,district,city column

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I have a location table (column: studentId,country, state, district, city) which has a millions of rows.
and wants to clean data the problem is

1. country name is not spell correctly some are missing (spelling mistake)
2. state name are missing and spelling mistakes/ not spell correctly, same with other column also (district, city)
3. some columns are filled with wrong information, country fill with city name and state fill with country name likewise.
4. the columns are filled with wrong information which wouldn't match with any country, state, district, city name

i wants to clean the data using snowflake

how to resolve this problem
please can anyone help me in that.

Comment: Unless you use (expensive) address validation software, there is no quick solution to cleaning up addresses - it's basically a manually process. One approach to solving some of your issues (assuming you have multiple instances of the same error) would be to do a "SELECT DISTINCT" on each column, write the result to a table and then manually add a column for the correct value. You can then use this table in an UPDATE statement to fix the data in that column